# Translate Firebase MLKit Bounding box coordinates to screen view coordinates

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I am using the `FirebaseVision` Object detection to detect things from the `CameraX` camera preview. It is detecting things find but I am trying to draw the bounding box of the items detected over the camera preview. In doing so the bounding box that firebase gives back is not for the image itself not the preview view to they appear in the wrong place.

The image size that I get back from firebase is `1200x1600` and the preview size is `2425x1440`

How do I translate the bounding boxes returned from firebase to the correct screen coordinates?

Comment: You can take a look at a good sample here https://github.com/javaherisaber/MLBarcodeScanner

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I ended up doing was I took the image size that the camera took, divided the width/height by the view width/height to get the scale size

```
if(isPortraitMode()){
    _scaleY = overlayView.height.toFloat() / imageWidth.toFloat()
    _scaleX = overlayView.width.toFloat() / imageHeight.toFloat()
}else{
    _scaleY = overlayView.height.toFloat() / imageHeight.toFloat()
    _scaleX = overlayView.width.toFloat() / imageWidth.toFloat()
}
```

Now that I have the scale I can then take the bounding box return by the firebase detector and translate the x and y coordinates by the scales

```
private fun translateX(x: Float): Float = x * _scaleX
private fun translateY(y: Float): Float = y * _scaleY

private fun translateRect(rect: Rect) = RectF(
    translateX(rect.left.toFloat()),
    translateY(rect.top.toFloat()),
    translateX(rect.right.toFloat()),
    translateY(rect.bottom.toFloat())
)
```

Which then gives you the scaled rect coordinates which you then draw on the screen

Comment: Based on this I created a github repo for barcode scanning and placing bounding box in right position, https://github.com/mtsahakis/barcode

Comment: This doesn't seem to consider aspect ratio is it?

Comment: @Ayyappa this assumes the preview view is being shown full screen, if your camera can crop or something then I doubt this will work

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @tyczj,

Your answer help me find my solution, let me add if someone is using front camera like me for Face detection you need to inverte the x axis, example:

```
val previewSize = overlayView.width.toFloat()
val newLeft = if (isFrontCamera) previewSize - (rect.right * scaleX) else rect.left * scaleX
val newRight = if (isFrontCamera) previewSize - (rect.left * scaleX) else rect.right * scaleX
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer in [CameraX qrcode scanner detect wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66583438/camerax-qrcode-scanner-detect-wrong/69407625#69407625). Basically you can use [CoordinateTransform](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/transform/CoordinateTransform) to transform coordinates from one CameraX UseCase to another.

Answer (score 0):

The solution now is to use `LifecycleCameraController` and `PreviewView` (both from CameraX) with `MlKitAnalyzer`. If you connect them with each other and then set `CameraController.COORDINATE_SYSTEM_VIEW_REFERENCED` as `targetCoordinateSystem` in `MlKitAnalyzer`, then the coordinates of the barcode bounding box will be automatically translated to the `PreviewView` coordinates. They will still be in pixels though, so you need to translate them further to `dp` using `LocalDensity.current` and `toDp()` function (in Compose).

For detailed example solution in Jetpack Compose see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77698616/4990683). For a good explanation of the separation of concerns between `CameraController` and `PreviewView` see [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/camerax-learn-how-to-use-cameracontroller-e3ed10fffecf).